# Pushing into an array differences in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I am wondering what is the difference between the two?

Scenario 1:

```
my @something = split(someregularexpressionhere, $somethinghere);
push(@{$hastable{$keyname}}, @something);
```

Scenario 2:

```
my $something = split(someregularexpressionhere, $somethinghere);
push(@{$hastable{$keyname}}, $something);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first scenario, `split` is in array context, and so `@something` contains the list of strings that result from the split. In the second scenario, `split` is in scalar context, and so `$something` contains the number of fields found.

Comment: Also, in scalar and void context it splits into the `@_` array in older Perls.

Comment: So, if I wanted to store the split words into an array in a hash table, the first scenario would be ideal? correct?

Comment: Yes. In general, I would avoid using split in scalar context, although there are specific cases in which it is useful and readable.